# RecyclerView return wrong position when scroll down and scroll up

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerView which have one viewHolder and many viewType, the issue when i scroll down and scroll up again i get different behaviors of recyclerView positions, I don't know what i missing here?

Here is my full adapter.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    int viewType = 0;

    if (position == 0) {
        viewType = 0;
    }else if (position == 1){
        viewType = 1;
    }else if (position == 2){
        viewType = 2;
    } else if (position == 3){
        viewType = 3;
    }

    return viewType;

}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_notification, parent, false);
    switch (viewType){
        case 0:
            return new MyViewHolder(v);
        case 1:
            return new MyViewHolder(v);
        case 2:
            return new MyViewHolder(v);
        case 3:
            return new MyViewHolder(v);
        default:
            return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final DataNotifications dataNotifications = list.get(position);
    int type = Integer.valueOf(dataNotifications.getStatue());
    ...
    switch (getItemViewType(type)){
        case 0:
            MyViewHolder myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
            ......
            break;
        case 1:
            MyViewHolder myViewHolderAccepted = (MyViewHolder) holder;
            .....
            break;
        case 2:
            MyViewHolder myViewHolderPending = (MyViewHolder) holder;
            ......
            break;
        case 3:
            MyViewHolder myViewHolderRefused = (MyViewHolder) holder;
            ....
            break;
    }

//        Glide.with(context).load(dataNotifications.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumnail);


    }
```

What may case this issue for me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show your recycler view code

Comment: @Salman500 this my adapter code, what you mean with recycle code ?

Comment: @pskink because there is a little difference in each view case.

Comment: @pskink yup it's working, but when i scroll up and down many times i got this behavior.

Comment: @pskink in my `onBindViewHolder` in every case in the switch statement i change a color or visible some items or some thing like that, i need to make this behavior stable, not to change after scroll many times.

Comment: see me your code where you are setting your adapter e.g "recycerlview.setAdapter(your_adapter);"

Comment: @pskink Well, it doesn't cover all behavior, in every  case i have different view holder behavior.

Comment: @pskink your sugetion will work, if i have same behaviors in many cases, but in my `onBindViewHolder` every case have it's own behviors of colors etc.